# What type of spy to use for testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I know when you use `spyOn` you can have different forms like `.and.callFake` or `.andCallThrough`. I'm not really sure which one I need for this code I'm trying to test...

```
  var lastPage = $cookies.get("ptLastPage");
      if (typeof lastPage !== "undefined") {
        $location.path(lastPage);
      } else {
        $location.path('/home'); //TRYING TO TEST THIS ELSE STATEMENT
      }
    }
```

Here is some of my test code:

```
describe('Spies on cookie.get', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function() {
      spyOn(cookies, 'get').and.callFake(function() {
        return undefined;
      });
    }));
    it("should work plz", function() {
      cookies.get();
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/home');
      expect(cookies.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(cookies.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
    });
  });
```

I've tried a lot of different things, but I'm trying to test the `else` statement. Therefore I need to make `cookies.get == undefined`.
Everytime I try to do that though, I get this error:

```
Expected '' to be '/home'.
```

The value of `location.path()` never changes when `cookies.get()` is equal to `undefined`. I think I'm using the spyOn incorrectly?

Follow-up on my mock values:

```
beforeEach(inject(
    function(_$location_, _$route_, _$rootScope_, _$cookies_) {
      location = _$location_;
      route = _$route_;
      rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      cookies = _$cookies_;
    }));
```

Follow-up on the functions:

```
angular.module('buildingServicesApp', [
   //data
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    //stuff
  .run(function($rootScope, $location, $http, $cookies)
```

No names on these functions, therefore how do I call the `cookies.get`?

Comment: What is `cookies`? Where did it come from? If this is supposed to mock `$cookies`, then it's wrong. `$cookies` isn't injected, and `cookies` isn't  `$cookies`.

Comment: There's a shortcut for that: `spyOn(cookies, 'get').and.returnValue(undefined);`

Comment: I added an edit to help clarify my mocks. Not sure if that's what you meant, but I did have those mocks in my code, they just weren't shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you're testing that the `location.path()` function works as designed. I'd say you should leave that testing to the AngularJS team :). Instead, verify that the function was called correctly:

```
  describe('Spies on cookie.get', function() {
    beforeEach((function() { // removed inject here, since you're not injecting anything
      spyOn(cookies, 'get').and.returnValue(undefined); // As @Thomas noted in the comments
      spyOn(location, 'path');
    }));
    it("should work plz", function() {
      // cookies.get(); replace with call to the function/code which calls cookies.get()
      expect(location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/home');
    });
  });
```

Note that you shouldn't be testing that your tests mock `cookies.get`, you should be testing that whatever function calls the first bit of code in your question is doing the right thing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the awesome response dude.
Unfortunately, my problem with calling the function/code is there isn't one?
That's been one of my issues...
I will add in another edit and explain.

Comment: You might take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24948577/215552. I'm afraid I don't know a lot about testing angular beyond controllers and directives.